# how to convert custom page url like pageurl.html in magento 2?

Tags: module, url-rewrite, magento2.3.4

I have a custom module page url like this: `www.example.com/style/index/content/id/19/`

I want to convert this url like this:  `www.example.stylecontent.html` with same content.

I have tried url rewrite but not getting success. can anyone help me to create this one?

> I don't want to use admin url rewrite.

I am using this code:

ma

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like that:

```
/**
* @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory
*/
protected $_urlRewriteFactory;

/**
* @param Context $context
* @param \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory
*/
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory
) {
    $this->_urlRewriteFactory = $urlRewriteFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context
    );
}

$urlRewriteModel = $this->_urlRewriteFactory->create()
/* set current store id */
$urlRewriteModel->setStoreId(1);
/* this url is not created by system so set as 0 */
$urlRewriteModel->setIsSystem(0);
/* unique identifier - set random unique value to id path */
$urlRewriteModel->setIdPath(rand(1, 100000));
/* set actual url path to target path field */
$urlRewriteModel->setTargetPath("www.example.com/customModule/customController/customAction");
/* set requested path which you want to create */
$urlRewriteModel->setRequestPath("www.example.com/xyz");
/* set current store id */
$urlRewriteModel->save();
```